# Real and continuous function with prescribed values

Tags: real-analysis

There is a real continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f(1/n)=(-1)^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Hint: is $f$ continuous at $x=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if such a continuous $f$ existed, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(1/n) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n) = f(0)$. But this is a problem because...

Comment: So this function does not exist !